# Can you use SSL/TLS for Websockets in Lagom?

Tags: ssl, lagom

I'm using the Lagom microservices framework and the Streaming requests and responses use websockets as the transport.  However, the built in websocket client (netty) doesn't handle SSL connections.  I understand there are various architectures where SSL termination isn't handled by Lagom itself that avoid this, but for our application we need TLS all the way to the endpoint.

The post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lagom-framework/QcOvK8H3R94) suggests that akka-http websockets support TLS, but that isn't currently an option as a Lagom client.

Answer (score 0):

This gist (https://gist.github.com/DaveDeCaprio/4db9d36a5e907fb5810c00e919347aa3) provides an example of an Akka HTTP websockets client for Lagom.

I don't include this as a full pull request in Lagom because it is still pretty hacky.  The biggest issue is that the RequestHeader that is returned from a streamed call is a fake, generic Ok header.  The actual HTTP call isn't made until the stream is materialized and run.  This is due to a different in the way akka http and netty handle the websockets.  This wasn't trivial to fix.